# How to configure a PC running pfsense to act as firewall for all network traffic

Tags: networking, router, firewall, pfsense

I am trying to set up PFsense in my network as a firewall between my modem (ATT modem and my WiFi 6 router). The setup I'm using is a PC with Ubuntu and VMware running PFsense. I have two network connections, one ethernet, and one USB ethernet. How should I configure PFsense to where using the connection coming out of the router and going into PFsense and coming out of PFsense and into the router "Internet" port. I know they have to be configured one "WAN" and the other "LAN", but that is about where my knowledge stops.

I have included a link to my picture of my network setup to help paint a picture.

[image]

Comment: Who's "they" and what part of this setwork dosen't work?

Comment: so configuring a router is reasonably simple, but there is a bit to it, so I'd start with the setup wizard: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/config/setup-wizard.html

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, sorry, I meant what how do the 2 ports "WAN" and "LAN" need to be configured to allow the packets to passthrough my PFsense device. And to your other question, regardless which port is coming from my modem and going to the router I still am unable to get the internet connection to go through my PFsense device.

Comment: @FrankThomas, thanks, I will give this another try!

Comment: so if you have gone through the wizard, and its not working, you may need to check your VM network configuration. are your VMWare nics configured for "bridged" mode? Personally I think your solution is unnecessarilly complex, and you should get rid of the VM, instead installing PFSense directly to the PC. additonally I'd get a PCIe Nic (theyre like 15$) to install in the PC, instead of some usb contraption. Both the VM and the software-dependent peripheral (usb nic) introduce issues with reliability that can't really be overcome. if you want reliable, ditch them both.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas, I have finally found the reason why I could not boot with a USB, (Stupid HP Secure Boot). I have installed pfSense straight onto the PC and I am configuring it as I type this.